# Debugging In-page I/O error - What logs should I request to better understand the issue at host?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012, event-log, windows-error-reporting, application-error

I had been entrusted with a task of my application failing intermittently on a Windows 2012 R2 Box with a network attached file server with the application code. The failure is typical

(14d4.1194): In-page I/O error c00000c4 - code c0000006 (first/second chance not available)

which indicates that the OS were unable to page in the memory. Management feels that it might be an OS bug and I have to analyze further.

I, being a developer and scantily trainer on server management need to understand the problem at source.

My question is, ***what sort of data should I request from the host to gather more information on the problem***?

My initial guess was **Event Log**. Is there anything more that we should ask?

Comment: run this tool and lokk if the SMART values are ok: http://crystalmark.info/software/CrystalDiskInfo/index-e.html Maybe the HDD is damaged

Comment: I'm going to finish closing this, but I'm not convinced it *should* be migrated, though I can't stop it.

Comment: Page faults are extremely well-tested. This is a feature decades old and run on 1 billion servers every day. It is not an OS bug but a hardware failure.

Comment: @usr: There is more than what is mentioned in this thread. The particular behavior is only observable when using a network file server with a 2012 r2 box. I am entrusted to investigate further.